# Best Way to check Bearer Token(JWT) before call WCF methods

Tags: c#, wcf, jwt, bearer-token

I need to implement an API that wraps a WCF service, all the controller methods are under Authorization via Bearer token

In the API configuration I add the WCF to the service

```
service.AddScoped<CheckOutMarketService>(config=>
{
    var client = new CheckOutMarketService(httpsBinding,url;
    return client;
});
```

In the Service class, called by the controller to execute the methods, I call the WCF directly, for example

```
public async Task<ReceiptOutput> GetReceipetByDocument(JsonInput input)
{
    if (checkToken(token)) // check token validation
    {
        var response = await _CheckOutMarketService(new ReceiptRequest
        {
           some_code.....
        });
    }
    else
    {
        authentication exception
    }

}
```

I would check the validity of the token so for each method of my API also because inserting the control on the WCF side is not possible, the question is is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the WCF service isn't performing any authentication or authorization _at all_? So anyone could fire-off SOAP requests at it and it would just blindly carry it out?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "validation", exactly? There are significant differences between validation, verification, authentication, and authorization and it sounds like you need to do all 4... in which case I'll say straight-away that your entire system design is compromised and needs rethinking, preferably by someone with experience in Internet security... (Also, how are those bearer-tokens being created? Are you using OAuth/OIDC? WS-Security? SAML?)

Comment: OAuth is used for tokens, the various WCF methods call within them an access validation method (via Userid and Sessionid that the API methods must pass), the token is used to authenticate API calls to the WCF

Comment: I think you could try using [Token Authenticator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/token-authenticator) to verify the token used with the message, verify that it is self-consistent, and verify the identity associated with the token. Or see if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553687/wcf-rest-token-based-authentication) can help you.

Comment: @LanHuang thanks, but those solutions involve some changes on the WCF side that I can't make

Comment: Hope these posts will help you.https://developers.onelogin.com/authentication/tools/jwt and https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens/validate-access-tokens and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690055/how-to-authenticate-validate-jwt-for-accessing-data-wcf-asp-net